# Incorrect proof of Fourier translation theorem

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to follow the proof of the Fourier shift theorem, which states:
$$
F[f(x-a)]=e^{-iwa}F[f(x)]
$$

There's one other [similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820805/proof-of-fourier-shift-theorem).  However, the only answer boils down to "what you're trying to do makes no sense".  I'm asking again to make the question more explicit.

What is wrong with the following logic?

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{The Fourier transform is }F[f(x-a)] & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-a)e^{-iwx}dx
\end{align*}
$$
Now my inclination is to define $\lambda=x-a$,so we can substitute $dx=d\lambda$ and $x=\lambda+a$.  But this results in a restatement of the Fourier transform with $\lambda$ instead of x, *and with a different and incorrect exponent*.
$$
\begin{align*}
F[f(\lambda)] & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\lambda)e^{-iw(\lambda+a)}d\lambda\\
 & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\lambda)e^{-iw\lambda}e^{-iwa}d\lambda\\
 & =e^{-iwa}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\lambda)e^{-iw\lambda}d\lambda\\
 & =\boxed{e^{-iwa}F[f(\lambda)]} \tag{This does not follow!}\\ 
F[f(x-a)] & =e^{-iwa}F[f(x-a)]
\end{align*}
$$

This result is inconsistent and contradicts the theorem.  Clearly I have a fundamental misunderstanding here somewhere... but what?

Comment: Would appreciate being told if there's a reason for the downvote.  I worked pretty hard to make this (a) concise, and (b) more clear than the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is almost correct, just in the last step observe:
\begin{align}
e^{-iwa}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\lambda)e^{-iw\lambda}d\lambda=e^{-iwa}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-iwx}dx,
\end{align}
And now one can continue your derivation as
\begin{align}
& F[f(x-a)]=e^{-iwa}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\lambda)e^{-iw\lambda}d\lambda= e^{-iwa}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-iw x}dx= e^{-iwa}F[f(x)].
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry I m confused here... it seems you are simply substituting $\lambda$ for x as a change of variable ...but $\lambda=x-a$ by your definition so how can you suddenly "forget" the a and say that $\lambda:=x$?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I forgot what integrals do.  The following step is so elementary that the proofs I reviewed didn't bother to state it:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\lambda)e^{-iw\lambda}d\lambda = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-iwx}dx\\$$

So taking over my "incorrect" proof at the integral wrt $\lambda$:
$$ \begin{align*}
 & =e^{-iwa}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\lambda)e^{-iw\lambda}d\lambda\\
 & =e^{-iwa}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-iwx}dx\\
 & =e^{-iwa}F[f(x)]
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: ahhh, i was just answering to you, while you added your own answer...

Comment: Looks like I beat you to it, but it's still much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I m confused here... it seems you are simply substituting $\lambda$ for x as a change of variable ...but $\lambda=x-a$ by your definition so how can you suddenly "forget" the a and say that $\lambda:=x$?